# compile openssl fails with "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz"

Tags: linux, compilation, openssl, makefile, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile from source "openssl-1.0.1j" but fails with message:
"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz"

Environment is debian wheezy on raspberry pi.

My files tree:
├── zlib-1.2.8
├   ├── lib sources
├   ├── libz.a
├
├── openssl-1.0.1j
├   ├── lib sources
├

I compiled successfully zlib-1.2.8 as follow:

```
$ cd ~/zlib-1.2.8  
$ ./configure --static  
$ make test
```

then tried to compile openssl -1.0.1j as follow:

```
$ cd ~/openssl-1.0.1j  
$ export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/zlib-1.2.8"  
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/zlib-1.2.8"  
$ export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/zlib-1.2.8"  
$ export LIBS="-l$HOME/zlib-1.2.8/libz.a"  
$ ./config threads zlib no-shared  
$ make
```

I'm looking to get to files tree:
├── zlib-1.2.8
├   ├── lib sources
├   ├── libz.a
├
├── openssl-1.0.1j
├   ├── lib sources
├   ├── libcrypto.a
├   ├── libss.a
├

What am I missing?

Comment: Does OpenSSL's `Configure` honor `export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/zlib-1.2.8"`? Or does it overwrite it with its own value? If its the later, then you will need to add it to `Makefile.org` by hand. Then do a `make clean && make dclean`.

Answer (score 0):

to config and compile openssl with static zlib (libz.a)

```
$ cd ~/openssl-1.0.1j
$ ./config threads no-shared zlib no-zlib-dynamic -L$HOME/zlib-1.2.8
$ make
$ make test
```

problem solved